# Enviar datos de MySQL Local a hosting automaticamente

Tags: mysql, hosting, localhost

Actualmente recojo datos de forma automática de varios sensores a unas tablas de una base de datos de MySQL en local. Me gustaría que estos datos se volcarán (imaginemos cada 5 minutos) a un hosting para tener backup y además poder acceder mediante una web en ese hosting a todos los datos etc.

¿De qué forma o qué herramienta puedo usar para ese volcado cada X tiempo?

Gracias y un saludo!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deberias de programar un servicio de windows en C# 
en el cual usas tus datos de tu base de datos de tu servidor 
por ej: sql.hosting.com user pass tabla etc... 
y haces un insert SQL

```
    INSERT INTO tablaDestino 
SELECT * FROM tablaOrigen
```

En caso de no saber programar un servicio realizas un programa sin interfaz por ej (consola)

y lo configuras en el programador de tareas de windows el .exe
[image: Programador de tareas]

[image: Crear tarea]

Comment: Gracias Jeff Fernando, entiendo que con este servicio podría apuntar a un hosting externo, cierto?

Comment: De nada, porsupuesto en tu .config

<connectionStrings>
<add name=”conexion” connectionString=”server="tudominio.com;database=test;user id=database_url;password=databse_password;” providerName=”MySql.Data.MySqlClient”/>
</connectionStrings>